# How to use preg_replace and strip_tags together in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to use preg_replace and strip_tags together on the same string?

I'm trying to remove HTML tags and all non_alpha_numeric characters from a string using the following :

```
<?=strip_tags (preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', ' ', $line['features']))?>,
```

This is currently removing the non_alpha characters but leaving the tags minus the brackets/parenthesis.

Anybody help?

Comment: Try to remove the tags first before doing preg_replace, this might fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your preg_replace is removing the "<" ">" values so strip_tags doesn't recognise them as tags,

if you reverse the functions

```
<?=preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', ' ', strip_tags($line['features']));?>
```

it should work